# Can $C_{10}$ be isomorphic to $C_5\times C_2$?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

$C_{10}$ is algebraically described by $a^{10}=1$. That's all. $C_{10}$ is $\{1,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6,a^7,a^8,a^9\}.$

$C_5\times C_2$ is algebraically described by $r^5=1$, $f^2=1$, and $rf=fr$. $C_5\times C_2$ is $\{1,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,f,fr,fr^2,fr^3,fr^4\}$.

Prove or disprove $C_{10}$ isomorphic to $C_5\times C_2$.

My question is : when construct the operation $\phi$ I got they are isomorphic. However, to definition of isomorphic graphs, $C_{10}$ with 10 edges while $C_5\times C_2$ has 15 edges, they cannot be isomorphic. That fact makes me confused. Please, explain me what's wrong, what's right?

Comment: Hello, Hoa. Are you positive $|C_5\times C_2|=15$?

Comment: If $C_n=\mathbb{Z}_n$, then yes, they are isomorphic: [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: @julien $C_n$ is notation for cyclic group of order $n$. Of course, we can show that every cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ of integers modulo $n$.

Comment: There are *many* different graph products, and it's not clear which one you have in mind.  Clearly whichever one you're thinking of is not identical to the direct product of groups: I see no reason to expect the definitions to intertwine just because they use the same symbol.

Comment: @Cortizol  $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is also the cyclic group of order $n$...They're all isomorphic, of course. $C_n$ is for those who prefer muliplication over addition. The point is: what is the structure on $C_n$ for the OP? He\she seems to define it first extensively for $C_{10}$, then by relations for $C_2\times C_5$. That's a bit messy...

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnRcc9eINaQ) useful for your strategy of visualizing groups as graphs. The relevant mathematics starts at about 2:00.

Answer (score 1):

Define a map $\phi : C_5 \times C_2 \to C_{10}$ by $\phi(r^u,f^v) = a^{2u + 5v}$.  Show now that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of groups.

Answer (score 1):

The two groups are indeed isomorphic. Since $C_{10}$ and $C_5\times C_2$ both have $10$ elements, it suffices to show that there is an element of order $10$ in $C_5\times C_2$ (i.e. a generator), because all cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic. I claim that $rf$ is a generator of $C_5\times C_2$. This is not hard to verify, so once you show this, you have shown that $C_{10}\cong C_5\times C_2$, and that the desired isomorphism is
\begin{align*}
\phi : C_{10}&\to C_{5}\times C_2\\
a&\mapsto fr
\end{align*}

Also, I'll note that the presentation of a group is not necessarily unique. We can describe a group with more generators than necessary, and that's what you've done in the case of $C_5\times C_2$. Since it's isomorphic to $C_{10}$, it can be presented the same way as $C_{10}$, but the presentation with two generators, $r$ and $f$, is also legitimate. If you look in the graph you've constructed of $C_5\times C_2$, you should be able to look at the edges defined by multiplication by $rf$ and see that there are $10$ of them. You could also make the graph of $C_{10}$ differently by looking at two sets of edges defined by multiplication by $a^2$ and $a^5$, respectively. That graph should look like your graph of $C_5\times C_2$.

Comment: @user73195 If you let $\phi$ be the homomorphism defined by $\phi(a) = r$, then $a^5$ is not mapped to $f$. A homomorphism of a cyclic group is uniquely determined by the image of its generator, and $\phi(a^5) = \phi(a)^5 = r^5 = 1$, so what you described is not a well-defined homomorphism: it fails to preserve the structure of $C_{10}$. If you define $\phi$ by $\phi(a^5) = f$ and $\phi(a^2) = r$, then this is the same as my homomorphism sending $\phi(a)$ to $rf$.

Comment: The fix is to send an element of order $5$ in $C_{10}$ to $r$ (an element of order $5$ in $C_5\times C_2$), and an element of order $2$ in $C_{10}$ to $f$ (an element of order $2$ in $C_5\times C_2$). After that you need to show that the function you defined is a well-defined homomorphism, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: they are: construct is \[\phi(1)\] =1; \[\phi(r)\]= a^6; \[\phi(r^2\] = a^2; \[\phi(r^3)\]= a^8; \[\phi(f)\]=a^5; \[\phi(fr)\]= a; \[\phi(fr^2)\]= a^7; \[\phi(fr^3)\]= a^3 and \[\phi(fr^4)\]= a^9

Comment: Looks like a respectable isomorphism to me!